# Wordpress: programmatically create sub menu for frontend

Tags: mysql, wordpress, plugins

I'd like to write a wordpress-plugin, where you can add a page.
If you submit the page it should also create a submenu under the menu "Teams".

Until now I can create a page through my code, but not the submenu.

I tried different functions I found on google, but nothing will work.

Does anyone know a function or a script that will help?

Comment: There is a site for WordPress development questions : http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

Yes sure, use the following as a sample to get you going.   The clause to check if you are in the right menu may need altering or deleting if you don't have multiple menu objects defined.

menu_item_parent is vital and that is the parent item uid.  find that by viewing your front end source code.  You should find that each menu item inserted via WP menu creating functions inserts the unique items id.

```
// add a sub menu dynamically via code!
function aj_add_menu_item( $items, $args ) {

// check we are in the right menu
if( $args -> theme_location =="primary" ) {

    $new_links = array();
    // Create a nav_menu_item object
    $newItem = array(
        'title'            => "Offers",
        'menu_item_parent' => 71,
        'ID'               => 'loginout',
        'db_id'            => '12312332', // something random
        'url'              => "offers",
        'classes'          => array( 'menu-item' )
    );

    $items[] = (object) $newItem;   // add to end of existing object.    
    menu_item_parent value will ensure it goes in right place
    return $items;

    }else{
        return $items;
    }
}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_objects', 'aj_add_menu_item', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Is it possible to add an <a title=""> attribute in the $newItem array?